# How to practice Mindfulness Meditation?

Tags: meditation-mindfulness

I have been researching this lately and thought it was amazing. I just don't know where to begin or know any techniques. Can someone list some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I m reading a dharma book (The Chinese Version), which 25 great beings demonstrated how they practiced mindfulness meditation.

The winner is: Guan Shi Yin Bodhisattva practices on hearing:
http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama5/shurangama5_12.asp

You might be interested to have a read of above link as well as 24 other practices.

May you be happy and at ease

Answer (score 4):

The word 'mindfulness' means '*to remember*' or '*keep in mind*'. In the context of Buddhism, it means 'to remember' to practise the factors of the eightfold path.

For example, if you are speaking/talking, you remember to speak in a manner that is honest, pleasant/gentle, cordial & beneficial. This is practising mindfulness meditation when meditating upon speech.

If practising formal sitting meditation, mindfulness is to remember to keep the mind in state that does not have desire for or get distressed about anything in the world.

Therefore, in formal sitting meditation, how to practise mindfulness meditation is to sit without desire or worry & just sit with natural quiet. When this is done properly, awareness of breathing will arise naturally as a sign of right mindfulness & later pleasant feelings will arise as a sign of right mindfulness.

Answer (score 3):

You won't learn this one from books, only by trying out and practicing it. The practice is to go beyond concepts like *Now I'm meditating*, *this is good, bad, me, mine...* and focus on the raw experience which is present. If you sit down to start meditating with the intention to be mindfull you might have the feeling *Now I'm meditating*, but in reality all you do is change postures.

You should have some basic instructions, but don't get into theory too much. It won't help you, it will only reinforce your opinions and ideas. I'd suggest to get to know the *framework* of **Right Mindfulness**, which are body, feelings, mindstates, mindobjects (*dhamma*).

The original teaching from the Buddha himself: [Satipatthana Sutta: The Foundations of Mindfulness](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.010.nysa.html)

A more practical guide from Ven. Yuttadhammo (the noting technique): [How to Meditate](http://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/)

Answer (score 2):

Try starting with [accesstoinsight.org](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/concmind.html), [Jon Kabat Zinn](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=jon%20kabat-zinn), [Joseph Goldstein](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f0mrUZ0Ga8&list=PLXmodMq3KyittfptG7wvcBfgR5ccaOnlb), [Google Search Inside Yourself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f0mrUZ0Ga8&list=PLXmodMq3KyittfptG7wvcBfgR5ccaOnlb).

Answer (score 2):

How about The Bhante Yuttadhammo channel on YouTube? He has a lot of useful videos but check out "How to Meditate" for beginners. His online  videos are beginner to intermediate on much more than only mindfulness and he gives meditation courses from beginner to advanced.

The teachers below teach about the same way as Bhante Yuttadhammo and are very beginner friendly:

Joseph Goldstein, Bhante Bodhidhamma,  Gil Fronsdal

Just Google one of the above names in quotes and add "Dhamma talks"

There's a Youtuber called "Stephen Proctor" who gives outstanding beginning teachings on mindfulness meditation in my opinion. Has anyone else heard of him? Is it just me or can this guy really teach or what?

These teachers practice  the same way I try to practice but there are a lot of good teachers who might have a different approach.

Comment: Just checked him out. Thanks for the tip (not Robinhood). Plus seems like he sticks to the program - no woken stuff.I've looked for decades for someone with pure practice without any philosophy. It's kind of interesting that you say "beginning." I usually find that appellation a bit demeaning. I know of many "advanced" practitioners who  yet watch the breath, recite Namo Amitaba, you get my point. For me personally in stuff like math, genetics, etc. when I hear that, I'm already looking for "advanced."

Answer (score 0):

The detail of the practice is outlined in [Satipatthana Sutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satipatthana_Sutta) and [Anapanasati Sutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anapanasati_Sutta), but these instruction maybe difficult to follow for a beginner. Best is to take a course in it. 2 organisations with a reasonably wide outreach are:

- http://www.internationalmeditationcentre.org/ and
- http://www.dhamma.org

or alternatively look for a teacher in [World Buddhist Directory](http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/).